# Swift `TARGET_` Defines does not work in a framework

Tags: xcode, swift2

I was try to make a framework what will run on iOS and OS X

The problem i found is that in a .framework the 'default' `TARGET_` defines do not work.

i'd like to use this code:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
    import UIKit
#endif
#if TARGET_OS_MAC
    import AppKit
#endif
```

but it fails, so i built a simple code for testing, and the results are not very nice (for me).

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    print("Hello iPhone")
#elseif TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
    print("Hello iPhone Simulator")
#elseif TARGET_OS_MAC
    print("Hello OS X")
#elseif TARGET_OS_TV
    print("Hello  TV")
#elseif TARGET_OS_NANO
    print("Hello Nano!")
#elseif TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED
    print("Hello Embedded?")
#else
    print("What kind of target are you!?")
#endif

// Prints What kind of target are you!?
```

The *framework.xcodeproj* is in the project of the iOS app.

so i was expecting *TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR*

Maybe someone knows how i can arrange this in a framework, i couldn't find a answer for it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution.

Using: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID31

```
#if os(value)
...
#endif
```

will work.

Supported values are: OSX, iOS, watchOS, tvOS

Example:

```
#if os(iOS)
    print("Hello iOS")
#elseif os(OSX)
    print("Hello OS X")
#elseif os(watchOS)
    print("Hello  Watch")
#elseif os(tvOS)
    print("Hello  TV")
#endif
```

I'll hope this can help someone else.